# How can I make transition property work in IE by using calc properties?

Tags: html, css

```
element1 {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}

element1:hover {
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

When I replace the calc in the height property by `px` or `%`, the transition works fine, but with the `calc`, just goes from one height to another without transition.

In other browsers it works fine, the problem is only in IE

---

Adding the code and [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/fyyqzpsL/1/) similar to my real situation.

```css
div{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    background: #1c8080;
    top: 158px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

div:hover{
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    top: 58px;
}

.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Height's tansition</p>
    <p>Works fine in Chrome, FF</p>
    <p class="bottom">But not in IE</p>
</div>
```

Yes, I know that in my case setting `bottom: 0` to the `<div>` and only changing the height, it also works but due to the bug in IE, that only changes from one height to another one, that is why I simulated the effect, changing the top position and the height.

So, how can I simulate that kind of effect in IE?

**Note**: I can't use Viewport units: `vh`, `vw`.

PD: the rare behavior with IE in my case is because the transition from `top: value` to `top: otherValue` works but the transition from `height: calc(value)` to `height: calc(otherValue)` does not, this is just to guide.

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you are doing, but there are known bugs in IE10-11 for `calc` being used in `transforms`. See [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814380/), they might be related

Comment: thank u, i have found this link in the one you posted https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform 
here the Internet Explorer Team admit it as a bug and said:
"We were able to validate your feedback. However, based on the limited impact this bug may have, we will not be able to address this bug during this release. "

Comment: Could you add working code snippet close to real situation? Maybe it's possible to do workaround with extra HTML layout.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov, I added a working code and jsfiddle close to my real situation. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/sg7qbpm5/1/)? Works like your code snippet (in my opinion), it's OK in IE10/IE11. Or I didn't understand your real situation.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #1c8080;
    top: 158px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

div:hover {
    top: 58px;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Height's transition</p>
    <p>Works fine in Chrome, FF</p>
    <p class="bottom">But not in IE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but the problem is that I don't know where the bottom will be, I just put it to the end as an example, but I really do not know where it'll be. Check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/jgh0k25r/

Comment: @YandYViera in your first code snippet (similar to your real situation as you said) you use `position: fixed`. In this case you always know about your `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` (relative to viewport). In your second case you use `position: absolute` and say you don't know where the bottom will be. I don't understand your real situation, why do you want to use `height: 100%`? What if parent element will be too small? For example http://oi60.tinypic.com/vpu9gi.jpg.

Comment: You are right, I had not realized until now, if I have the top and the height I can calculate the bottom, even in my particular  case whit position: absolute, so your answer solved my problem, I'm really thankful.

Comment: Anyway it's a shame not function calc() with transition in IE. I do not think this bug has a limited impact as they say, we should let them know to see if they fix it